# executing JavaScript function with <a href>

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="" id="category_button">Categories</a>
```

and this function:

```
$(function() {
var bar3 = $('footerSlideContainer_mobile');

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
        bar3.stop().animate({ height: '250px' });
    } else {
        bar3.stop().animate({ height: '0px' });
    }
});
});
```

Right now the function is called when the user scrolls down. But I would like to call it when a user clicks on the `<a>` tag. I would appreciate some help! Thanks you!

Comment: replace `$(window).scroll(...)` with `$('#category_button').click(...)`

Comment: I tried that, but the if-statement still gets in the way right? because its using some scroll-parameters

Comment: `this` refers to the element that triggered the event. Since originally that was `window`, it behaved as expected. If you do what I mentioned earlier, then `this` now refers to the `a` tag. Replace `$(this)` with `$(window)` to restore the correct functionality

Answer (score 1):

This should call a javascript method when you click the link:

```
<a href="" onclick="jsfunction()" id="category_button">Categories</a>

<script>
function jsfunction(){
   var bar3 = $('footerSlideContainer_mobile');

   if($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
     bar3.stop().animate({ height: '250px' });
   }else {
     bar3.stop().animate({ height: '0px' });
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var bar3 = $('footerSlideContainer_mobile');

    $('#category_button').scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
            bar3.stop().animate({ height: '250px' });
        } else {
            bar3.stop().animate({ height: '0px' });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but how does this line `if($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {` fit? 
and shouldn't it be .click?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a section hash (#) to the href of the anchor link.  This prevents the link from actually redirecting to a new URL (you are fooling the anchor link to try to scroll to a different location in the same page).  This will add a "#" to the end of your current URL, but it will not affect any of your query parameters.

```
<a href="#" id="category_button">Category</href>
```

Then, simply wrap your scroll function inside a click function

```
$(document).on('click','#category_button',function(){
    var bar3 = $('footerSlideContainer_mobile');

    if($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
        bar3.stop().animate({ height: '250px' });
    } else {
        bar3.stop().animate({ height: '0px' });
    }

});
```